# Size of object in Blender is not correct

Tags: python, blender

I wrote python and put the length = 192' in imperial units. But when I measure the distance  using 't' I get 1200'. I am using Blender 3.0 scripting. I have asked this question before but did not get a reply.

[Size of object in Blender not correct,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70804495/size-of-object-in-blender-not-correct)

Am I missing something?

```
import bpy
tall = 7
inchesinfeet = 12
#horizontal pieces
length = 192
 #x
width = 4 #y
height = 2 #z
#vertical pieces
thick = 2 #x
wide = 2 #y
ceiling = tall*inchesinfeet #z
oncenter = 18

# bottom
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(length/2, 0, 0), scale=(length, 1, 1))

# sides left first
print("length = " + str(length))
'''
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(width, depth,) (tall*inchesinfeet+2*height)), scale=(width, depth, ))
```

[image]

Comment: You could set a bounty on your question.

Comment: Please don't repost questions: [How do I get attention for one of my own questions without a good answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/248627)

Comment: Ok I've added a bounty to the question. Thanks

Comment: I have voted to delete this question. Please add your delete vote, so it is removed.